# Connection losses via HDMI?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, external-display

I own an Acer Nitro 5 (AN515-51-536M). I am using a desktop pc right now, but I am considering using my notebook as main working station. My notebook has 1 HDMI, 2 USB 2.0, 1 USB 3.0 and 1 USB-C Port.

My first question is: Will HDMI limit the fps refresh rate on the laptop screen if I connect a display with that port? My notebook supports FULL HD 1080p.

My other question is: I want to connect 2 displays to the notebook: one with HDMI for gaming and graphical work; and another one via docking station with my USB-C hub for pure coding, streaming and surfing. Will I possibly encounter any problems?

My notebook has the following specs:

Intel® Core™ i5 (7. Generation) 7300HQ Prozessor 4x 2,50 -3.5 GH

GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB

8GB DDR4